# Python classes in Java GUI

Tags: java, python, jython

I am working on Java project with a lot off mathematics. I wonder is possible to put Python classes into Java GUI ( simple part is JTextField to be Python so I don't need parsing string, just call interpreter Python ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) but I've never used it so I can't say if it works with the java gui stuff. What is it that you're trying to do? Why do you want to use python instead of java? Why can't you just write the entire thing in java?